# Elm: Function `send` expecting Http.Request String but it is Http.Request Bool

Tags: http, functional-programming, elm

I'm setting up a super simple `http` call to an endpoint on my server which returns a JSON response - an object with a `success` prop which is a boolean. Here is the relevant code:

```
getData : Model -> Cmd Msg
getData { userId, data } =
    let
        url =
            "/get-data?userId=" ++ userId ++ "&data=" ++ data

        request =
            Http.get url decodeGetData

    in
        Http.send GetDataResult request


decodeGetData : Decode.Decoder Bool
decodeGetData =
  Decode.at [ "success" ] Decode.bool
```

I'm getting the following error from the compiler:

```
Http.send GetDataResult request
                        ^^^^^^^
Function `send` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:
    Http.Request String
But it is:
    Http.Request Bool
```

What's going wrong here? How do I set up Http.send to expect a Bool instead of a string? I know that the basic setup of my request is correct because my code compiles if I change the `decodeGetData` function to:

```
decodeGetData : Decode.Decoder String
decodeGetData =
  Decode.at [ "success" ] Decode.string
```

In this case I can successfully make the http request, but then I get an error because the success prop on the response is a boolean instead of a string.

Any pointers? Cheers!

Comment: Your error message is referencing `GrabCashResult` whereas the code snippet above it is referencing `GetDataResult`. Is that intentional or could that be the cause of the compile error?

Comment: Nah that's just my mistake in copying an older version of the error and a newer version of the code. Error is still there when they're the same. (Edited question to make them the same)

Comment: Gotcha. Can you also include the definition of `Msg` and/or the `GetDataResult` constructor? Does it take a Bool or String argument?

Comment: A good question! This put me on the right track. My mistake was that I had `GetDataResult (Result Http.Error String)`. Hadn't really investigated that because the error message was pointing me to the other file. All good once I changed it to `GetDataResult (Result Http.Error Bool)` - Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you pasted in all looks good, which leads me to think that the problem lies in a piece of code you don't have listed. Namely, the `Msg` constructor `GetDataResult` should have a single parameter of type `Result Http.Error Bool`. The compiler error you received would occur if the signature were instead `Result Http.Error String`.